# How do i display texts to a particular sentence in the HTML using event-listener in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, event-listener

I am having difficulty working with DOM for a paticular project that i am working on.
My goal is to get the header name of each cards when clicked and displaying in the blank space of the summary below it "Order Summary.

Problem Encoutered:

- The first three cards are the only ones working right while the rest keeps throwing type error when i tried using console.log and i couldn't find what the issue is cause console showed me each individual details for the cards at each click but when i try to display the innertext of a particular cards aside the first three cards, it throws error when i click on the those cards but works fine with the first three cards which i do not know how that was even possible since the first three cards do not own any of the classes after them.

I will be providing the code below of which i have given a little style in case you want to copy and paste on code pen to test. Thank you so much.

Here is the HTML CODE

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  
    <div class="steps__wrapper">

         <div class="steps__track plans__option">
          <div class="steps__title">
            <h1>How do you drink your coffee?</h1>
            <img src="images/icon-arrow.20551347.svg" alt="arow icon" class="arrow-icon">
          </div>
         <div class="plan-option-container">
          <div class="plan-wrapper">

<!--I ADDED EVENT LISTENER TO THE CARD-->
<!--THERE ARE 15 CARDS IN TOTAL-->
            <div class="product__plan">
<!--H2 HERE IS THE TITLE CLASS I WANT TO EXTRACT-->
             <h2  class="product__plan--title brewed-type">Capsule</h2>
             <p  class="product__plan--description">Compatible with Nespresso systems and similae brewers</p>
            </div>
            <div class="product__plan">
             <h2  class="product__plan--title  brewed-type">Filter</h2>
             <p  class="product__plan--description">For pour over or drip methods like Aeropress, Chemex, and V60</p>
            </div>
            <div class="product__plan">
             <h2  class="product__plan--title brewed-type">Espresso</h2>
             <p  class="product__plan--description">Dense and finely ground beans for an intense, flavoful experience</p>
            </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         </div>
         <div class="steps__track plans__option">
          <div class="steps__title">
            <h1>What type of coffee?</h1>
            <img src="images/icon-arrow.20551347.svg" alt="arow icon" class="arrow-icon">
          </div>
         <div class="plan-option-container">
          <div class="plan-wrapper">
            <div class="product__plan">
              <h2  class="product__plan--title coffee-type" >Single Origin</h2>
              <p  class="product__plan--description">Distinct, high quality coffee from a specific family-owned farm.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="product__plan">
              <h2  class="product__plan--title coffee-type" >Decaf</h2>
              <p  class="product__plan--description">Just like regular coffee, except the caffeine has been removed</p>
            </div>
            <div class="product__plan">
              <h2  class="product__plan--title coffee-type" >Blended</h2>
              <p  class="product__plan--description">Combination of two or three dark roasted beans of organic coffees</p>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
         </div>
         <div class="steps__track plans__option">
          <div class="steps__title">
            <h1>How much would you like</h1>
            <img src="images/icon-arrow.20551347.svg" alt="arow icon" class="arrow-icon">
          </div>
          <div class="plan-option-container">
            <div class="plan-wrapper">
              <div class="product__plan ">
                <h2  class="product__plan--title coffee-quantity">250g</h2>
                <p  class="product__plan--description">Perfect for the solo drinker. Yield about 12 delicious cups.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="product__plan ">
                <h2  class="product__plan--title coffee-quantity">500g</h2>
                <p  class="product__plan--description">Perfect option for a couple. Yields about 40 delectable cups.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="product__plan ">
                <h2  class="product__plan--title coffee-quantity">1000g</h2>
                <p  class="product__plan--description">Perfect for offices and events. Yield about 90 delightful cups.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="steps__track plans__option grinding">
          <div class="steps__title">
            <h1>Want us to grind them?</h1>
            <img src="images/icon-arrow.20551347.svg" alt="arow icon" class="arrow-icon">
          </div>
         <div class="plan-option-container">
          <div class="plan-wrapper">
            <div class="product__plan">
              <h2  class="product__plan--title coffee-process">Wholebean</h2>
              <p  class="product__plan--description">Best choice if you cherish the full sensory experience</p>
            </div>
            <div class="product__plan">
              <h2  class="product__plan--title coffee-process">Filter</h2>
              <p  class="product__plan--description">For drip or pour-over coffee methods such as V60 or Aeropresso</p>
            </div>
            <div class="product__plan">
              <h2  class="product__plan--title coffee-process" >
                Cafetiére</h2>
                <p  class="product__plan--description">Course ground beans specially suited for french press coffee</p>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
         </div>
        

         <div class="steps__track plans__option">
          <div class="steps__title">
            <h1>How often do we deliver?</h1>
            <img src="images/icon-arrow.20551347.svg" alt="arow icon" class="arrow-icon">
          </div>
        <div class="plan-option-container">
          <div class="plan-wrapper">
            <div class="product__plan ">
              <h2  class="product__plan--title coffee-delivery">Every week</h2>
              <p  class="product__plan--description price-plan"><span class="price">$7.20</span> per shipment. Includes free first-class shipping</p>
            </div>
            <div class="product__plan ">
              <h2  class="product__plan--title coffee-delivery">Every 2 week</h2>
              <p class="product__plan--description price-plan"><span id="price">$9.60</span> per shipment. Includes free priority shipping.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="product__plan ">
              <h2 class="product__plan--title coffee-delivery">Every month</h2>
              <p class="product__plan--description price-plan"><span id="price">$12.00</span> per shipment includes free priority shipping</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class="summary">

<!--ORDER SUMMARY WHERE I WANT TO DISPLAY THE INNERTEXT TAKEN FROM THE TITLE-->

            <h1 class="summary__title">ORDER SUMMARY</h1>
          <p>
            “I drink my coffee as <span class="drink-style style">_____</span>, with a <span class="type style"> _____</span> type
            of bean. <span class="quantity style">_____</span>  ground ala <span class="grind style">_____</span> , sent to me<span class="delivery  style">_____</span>.”</span>
          </p>
          </div>
         
         </div>

          </div>
</body>

</html>
```

"

I gave the CSS a little quick styling to help you help me figure my problem out faster

```
.plan-wrapper{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.product__plan{
  border.1em solid red;
  background:red;
  margin:1em ;
}
```

The javscript code:

````
let planCards=document.getElementsByClassName("product__plan")
let brewedTypes=document.getElementsByClassName("brewed-type")
let coffeeTypes=document.querySelectorAll(".coffee-type")
let coffeeQuantity=document.getElementsByClassName("coffee-quantity")
let coffeeProcess=document.getElementsByClassName("coffee-process")
let coffeeDelivery=document.getElementsByClassName("coffee-delivery")

for(let i=0;i<planCards.length;i++){
  planCards[i].addEventListener("click",()=>{
    //GET THE INNERTEXT OF THE ELEMENT AND DISPLAY IT THE ORDER SUMMARY
    let brewedTypesEl=brewedTypes[i].innerText
    document.querySelector(".drink-style").innerText=brewedTypesEl
   let coffeeTypesEl=coffeeTypes[i].innerText
   document.querySelector(".type").innerText=coffeeTypesEl
    let coffeeQuantityEl=coffeeQuantity[i].innerText
    document.querySelector(".quantity").innerText=coffeeQuantityEl
    let coffeeProcessEl=coffeeProcess[i].innerText
    document.querySelector(".grind").innerText=coffeeProcessEl
    let coffeeDeliveryEl=coffeeDelivery[i].innerText
  document.querySelector(".delivery").innerText=coffeeDeliveryEl
  })
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are trying to access elements from different arrays with the same index. In your case, the brewedTypes, coffeeTypes, coffeeQuantity, coffeeProcess, and coffeeDelivery arrays have different lengths, yet you're trying to access their elements using the same index within the event listener callback function.

The array planCards is composed of all the .product__plan elements which sum up to 15 cards while the other arrays: brewedTypes, coffeeTypes, coffeeQuantity, coffeeProcess, and coffeeDelivery have lengths that are not equal to 15. Thus, for indices beyond the length of these arrays, you get an error.

A solution would be to ensure that each card only listens for the click event to update the appropriate part of the order summary.

Like so:

```
let planCards = document.getElementsByClassName("product__plan")

//Function to get the title of a card
const getTitle = (element) => {
    return element.querySelector('.product__plan--title').innerText;
}

for (let i = 0; i < planCards.length; i++) {
    planCards[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
        let title = getTitle(planCards[i]);

        //Assign the title to the correct part of the summary based on the class of the title
        if (planCards[i].querySelector('.product__plan--title').classList.contains('brewed-type')) {
            document.querySelector(".drink-style").innerText = title;
        } else if (planCards[i].querySelector('.product__plan--title').classList.contains('coffee-type')) {
            document.querySelector(".type").innerText = title;
        } else if (planCards[i].querySelector('.product__plan--title').classList.contains('coffee-quantity')) {
            document.querySelector(".quantity").innerText = title;
        } else if (planCards[i].querySelector('.product__plan--title').classList.contains('coffee-process')) {
            document.querySelector(".grind").innerText = title;
        } else if (planCards[i].querySelector('.product__plan--title').classList.contains('coffee-delivery')) {
            document.querySelector(".delivery").innerText = title;
        }
    })
}
```

When each card is clicked, the function getTitle is called to get the inner text of the title of the card. It then checks which class the title contains and then updates the appropriate part of the order summary. This solution ensures that only the appropriate part of the order summary is updated when a card is clicked.

Comment: I have done that but my problem is it is only working for the first three cards

Comment: @Olaitan check my edited post, that should be a solution for this